# Complex numbers finding real values

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I am trying to solve for x and y using the following equation:
$4i + 2 = \frac{x + iy + 5 + 4i}{2x + 2iy - 5}$

I got it down to real and imaginary, but am unsure what to do next.
$3x-8y-15=(-8x-3y+24)i$

Comment: You concluded that a real number is equal to an imaginary number. When does that happen? Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose a,b are two real numbers,if we are having a=ib as some condition,as a,b are real they can be equal only when both of the sides of equation are zero. So a=b=0.you can proceed with your problem now.

Comment: @mjw thanks for pointing out I edited the answer

Comment: Thank you!${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Assuming $\ x,y\ $ are required to be real numbers, then equating the real and imaginary parts of both sides of the equation
$$
3x-8y-15=(-8x-3y+24)i
$$
will give you two linear equations in $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ which you can solve to obtain their valuea.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by equating? This is what my original question was trying to figure out

Comment: If $\ z_1=x_1+iy_1\ $ and $\ z_2=x_2+iy_2\ $ are two complex numbers then $\ z_1=z_2\ $ if and only if the real parts, $\ x_1\ $ and $\  x_2\ $, of $\ z_1\ $ and $\ z_2\ $ are the same, and their imaginary parts, $\ y_1\ $ and $\  y_2\ $, are the same.  Applying this principle to declare that $\ x_1=x_2\ $ and $\ y_1=y_2\ $ is called "equating real and imaginary parts".   In your case the real and imaginary parts of $\ 3x-8y-15\ $ are $\ 3x-8y-15\ $ and $\ 0\ $ respectively, and the real and imaginary parts of $\ (-8x-3y+24y)i\ $ are $\ 0\ $ and $\ -8x-3y+24y\ $ respectively.